# How do I get an NSDate from a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string, nsdate

I am trying to get an `NSDate` from a string. The problem I am having is that the date I need is within a text.

Example: “Expieres : 26 May 2015 140 days left”.

I would like “26 May 2015” out of that and convert it into an `NSDate`. Would I use Regular expression, then convert the string to `NSDate`. If so, what would the regular expression look like.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `@"\\d{2} [A-Za-z]+ \\d{4}"` This is extremely lax regex. Your single example is not enough to tell whether you need a stricter one.

Comment: @nhahtdh, you should post your reply as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: @DuncanC: This is another uninteresting and underspecified question. Sorry, but I don't care enough to post an answer.

Comment: @danypata: No, it is not a dup of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are gazillion ways to match the date. Depending on the actual input and purpose, you may or may not need a strong regex to match what you want.

One simple solution (while reasonably strict) is:

```
@"\\d{2} [A-Za-z]+ \\d{4}"
```

Comment: regex made it look more beautiful...